# Using ckeditor in asp.net class library

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ckeditor, class-library

I need to create a class library with title and body template. Both title and body are textboxes. In the body I want to use CKEditor as text editor. Further, the editor contains `ImageBrowser.aspx` and `LinkBrowser.aspx` for browsing images and files.

So far, I have used CKEditor directly in aspx page. But now I am going to use it in a class library so that I can have a dll file that I will use in my web application.

What's the way out? Seeking advices. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

someone has already done it for you - http://syrinxckeditor.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thank you so much for the  link. I tried it and found helpful. But all it helps is: now I don't need to manually turn a textbox into ckeditor. But still I need to include ckeditor files in my site. Is there any way I can integrate all those in a single dll?

Comment: that would be a lot of work, and an ongoing maintenance headache.  You will save yourself a lot of hassle by just using what is available.

Comment: @sangam you can embed the resource files into dll, trying searching this

Answer (score 1):

I did a CMS a while ago which is free to use and all the other GPL stuff. I use CKEditor to provide the content editing across the solution. If you like download it and see how its done.

http://hci.me.uk/contentmanagement/

In the solution the following files are involved in the WYSIWYG content editing:

1. App_Code Folder: Content.cs
2. App_Data Folder: content.xml
3. FCKEditor folder
4. UserControls Folder: ContentManager.ascx, ContentManager.ascx.cs

They present a ckeditor when user the logged in to edit various sections and then content is saved on the xml file. There is also folder to uploading stuff from the editor and managing the files.

Hope this helps you

Comment: Oh XGreen! That's a good job done and indeed helpful to get a start on cms. Although my question of having ckeditor into a dll is not addressed, you deserve a +1.